# Passing string to javascript function in razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, string-literals

I am passing 3 parameters to a javascript function from razor code, the first two are passed properly but the third one is never passed - the first two are int/numbers but the last one is a string

**THIS WORKS FINE**

```
if (geResult.ResultValue != null) { 
    var val = "A!";
    <script>{ getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId, @index, "A!"); }</script>
}
```

**THIS DOESNOT WORK**

```
if (geResult.ResultValue != null) { 
    var val = "A!";
    <script>{ getPosition(@geResult.assessmentId, @index, @val); }</script>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this--Just add single quotes

```
if (geResult.ResultValue != null) { 
<script>{ getPosition('@geResult.assessmentId', '@index', '@val'); }</script>
}
```

Hope it Works..

Comment: Great! so it was single quotes!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a more robust implementation you could generate a json object from razor instead of passing single parameters. This is especially handy if you are passing booleans and/or strings. There is no need to quote or interpret your razor variables since Json.Encode takes care of this.

In order to generate the object try this:

```
var parameters =  JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { assessmentId = geResult.assessmentId, index = index, value = val }))');
```

Json.Encode converts an AnonymousType from razor to json. 
@Html.Raw prevents encoding of the markup.

The result is a json object that is rendered as a string for the client to use. When the client parses the text using JSON.parse() or if you are using jQuery use jQuery.parseJSON() the result is an object containing your razor parameters.